# Can conditioning and the amount of head space

Tags: bottle-conditioning

I recently just purchased an oktober sl1 can sealer... I am looking for some intel as far as how much head space do I leave before I seal the lid? Because cans have such a larger surface area at the top as compared to a neck of a bottle i am trying to figure out what the appropriate amount would be? Any info would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/24283/beer-bottle-vs-can-head-space-carbonation-and-conditioning?rq=1

Comment: Are you conditioning in the can?

Comment: Yes I will be using priming sugar and conditioning in the can